# Cannot step past first instruction in Keil disassembly window

Tags: keil, nrf51, nrf52

When I run the UART app `nRF5_SDK_12.3.0_d7731ad\examples\peripheral\uart` in debug mode, the disassembly window opens, and I seem to get stuck on the first instruction. `Step over` doesn't step past the first instruction. Why is that? Thank you.

[image]

Here is my debug settings

[image]

Here is my advanced debug settings

[image]

Here are the instructions I've following for setting the J-link debugger settings

http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/jlink/jlink_cortexdebug.htm

I've tried flashing the soft device before flashing the app, but the flash fails in that case. The app only flashes if I erase the chip first indicating the soft device is flashed with the app (right?).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you had run a project need softdevice.

And you should find the reason why you can't flash that softdevice.

Then, you should make sure the start address of burning is compatible with the softdevice.